# Sliding tab's background disappears at the scrolling / overflow portion

Tags: css, background, scrollbar, overflow, slidingmenu

Sliding tab CSS is as follows:

```
#tab_slide {
    overflow-x: auto; // added by me for vertical scrollbar
    overflow-y: auto; // added by me for vertical scrollbar
    height: 100%!important; // added by me for vertical scrollbar
    color: #000; 
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    top: 5%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

The CSS for the slide tab background is as follows:

```
#tab_slide_background {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Unfortunately if there is any overflow and the scrollbar appears, there is no background when you scroll down.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

The website in question is at http://thehungrygeek.com

I would appreciate any help in figuring out how to make the background appear when the user has to scroll down (i.e. user's display height is smaller than slide tab content)!

Comment: problem is "`#tab_slide {height:100%}` " , but if you remove that panel would not be scrollable anymore.

Comment: yep you're right... is there any way to get a scrollable panel without getting the background messed up?

Comment: yes, but the jQuery code will have to be in safe mode

also ideally I do not really want the tab to be 100% of the page height, I'd rather the tab end where the content ends. I only did the height: 100% to get the vertical scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the height of content then apply the same to background div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var heightPanel = $('#tab_slide_include').height();
    $('#tab_slide_background').height(heightPanel);
});
</script>
```

Add this code after loading your jQuery file. I hope you know where you have used jQuery file. ;)

Comment: thanks for the post, could you clarify a bit about the implementation of the solution? not to sure where to put those lines

Comment: I've successfully implemented jQuery code on the site in the past. Tried putting your fix in but it didn't work.

I had to replace $ with jQuery since its in safe mode. You can have a look at the site's source code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, gave up on putting a scrollbar on the sidebar.

Ended up using:

```
#tab_slide {
top: 50%
margin-top:-410px!important;
}
```